# Schedule running function every 60 seconds?

Tags: python, mysql, jython, scheduler

Can someone make and explain scheduler for me, which runs this, every 60 seconds?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM economy"
cursor.execute(sql)
brojredova = cursor.rowcount
for i in range(1, brojredova):
sql2 = "UPDATE economy SET LoanTime= LoanTime - 1 WHERE ID = '%d' AND Loan > 0" % (i)
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues do you have with whatever you tried?

Comment: @admdrew I haven't tried yet, because I can't figure out how it works, how to set it to work for every 60 secounds... That's why I asked for explanation...

Comment: Ok. What sort of research on the internet have you done so far?

Comment: @admdrew I was googling for scheduler, but can't realise how it works, I'd like to get example on this, with explanation, so I can do other things like this too...

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like you don't have a minimal understanding of the topic you have a question on. Once you have done additional troubleshooting/research and are still stuck on something specific, I would recommend posting a new question at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling can be done in many ways, including using your system's native scheduler and having it call your program every 60 seconds. The simplest solution is to put your stuff in a while loop and use time.sleep:

```
import time

while True:
    start = time.time()
    do_your_work_here()
    timeout = time.time() - start - 60.
    if timeout > 0.:
        time.sleep(timeout)
```

Comment: Ok, but as far as I know, that stops whole file, not just that function? I have other functions that need to be independent, and without timer...

Comment: That's a new and rather complicated requirement! The code looks like it can run independently, which makes it a good candidate to run in a separate thread or as a separate process completely. But that's far beyond the scope of the question asked. You'll need to do some design work.